# What does "if var" mean in python?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, semantics

This is a function in python to validate a day entry.

```py
def valid_day(day):
    if day and day.isdigit():#if day
        day = int(day)
        if day > 0 and day <= 31:
            return day
```

I want to know what the expression `if day` means (in terms of semantics).

I only know the effect of `if` on boolean expressions not on variables like integers or arrays.

Comment: FWIW, the function you give *could* be documented as: "'day' is expected to be None, or a possibly-empty string of digits; the result will be integer in range 1..31 (if conversion to such can be done) or None in other cases".

Comment: One small addition. The last condition could be written as `if 0 < day <= 31`.

Comment: While we are picking those nits - I'd write it as  1 <= day <= 31.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Python, writing

`if var:`

has the same effect as writing

`if bool(var):`

(where `bool` is the built-in `bool` type which also acts as a constructor function for bool objects).

If the value is already a bool (valued True or False) the meaning is clear -- `bool(var)` returns the same value. For other types, there's almost always a conversion to bool available which depends on the type. For integers (as in C) it's the same as `var!=0`; for lists or dicts or strings, it's the same as `len(var)!=0`, and so forth. You can find this in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

When you define your own class you can define a method via `def __nonzero__(self):` , which will be called in this context (when your object is passed to `bool` explicitly, or implicitly in an `if` -- or `while` for that matter).

A notable exception: numpy array objects do not convert to bool (they raise an exception). They need to be explicitly converted using constructs like `(arr!=0).any()` or `(arr>0).all()`

On similar lines: Don't get into the habit of writing any of

```
if x == True:     # This only works as expected when x is a bool, or 0, or 1
if x is True:     # Can be useful but you need to understand what it really means.
if x == None:     # Often works as expected, except when it doesn't
```

Comparison to None should always be done with

`if x is None:`
(or)
`if x is not None:`

There is only one `None` object, and `x is None` will tell you if x refers to that object, and will always give you a bool (True if so, False for any other object). Comparing `x==None` (a mistake I frequently made when starting to use Python) will usually work, but it activates the generic comparison machinery of Python, which is not what you probably want; if `x` is an instance of a class, the comparison could raise an exception. `is` is simple and quick and just does that identity test - it can't be overloaded.

Likewise, `if x is True` means "if x is the boolean object meaning true, and no other object at all" -- which can be useful, but is too narrow for the case when you are just testing truth value. Somebody might end up passing 1, which will fail an 'is True' test, but otherwise acts very much like True.

Comment: I've noticed that many programmers tend to have a style which is sort of 'in denial' of boolean expressions; they write `if(boolvar==true)` (I'm in C++ now) and, worse, `if(x<0)is_neg = true; else isneg=false;` I'm never sure whether they don't know that it can be simpler, or they just prefer it to be more complicated. Or maybe this is a style learned from other languages (fortran? matlab?) where you have to do these things?

Comment: This looks that the perfect way to check if a object is None, without using the ugly syntax `if var is None`, or even worst `if var is not None`.

Comment: @Gojir4  what does? I haven't suggested any alternative and have in fact recommended against `var==None`. What's "ugly" about `var is None`, if that's what you want to test for?

Comment: @greggo, it's not so much that "var is None" is ugly but rather that forgetting the "is None" is an easy mistake to make. Therefore, if one has a type that is nominally integer (or boolean for that matter) but may also be None, then it is best to implement `__nonzero__`.

Comment: @KeithHanlan I'm not sure what you're saying. `if var is None` tests if `var` is the `None` object. Omit the `is None` and you're testing the truth-value of `var`, which is a different operation. No amount of implementing `__nonzero__` can change that (you can only change what a class type defines to be its own truth value).

Comment: @greggo, Sorry for the confusion. I meant to direct my comment to Gojir4 who referred to the "is None" syntax as "ugly". We are on the same page.

Answer (score 8):

Behaviour differs a little bit from language to language.

**Behaviour 1:**
The variable is converted into a boolean. I.e. there are language specific conversions from different types into a boolean. For numeric values, `0` is usually converted into `false` while any other value is converted to `true`. As far as I know, this is the way Python does it.

**Behaviour 2:**
Booleans are numeric values. As above, `0` is usually the only value that evaluates to `false`

**Behaviour 3:**
Any non-null reference evaluates to `true`, null references evaluate to `false`.

This should more or less cover it, but there may be other variations or combinations as well, for instance using fallback to method 2 or 3 if 1 is not available. The point is that it's very much a language specific question.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that, e.g `''`, empty lists and `None` (among others) is evaluated to False.

Comment: "I.e. there are language specific conversions from different types into a boolean." covers that, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry about that - i missed the `for numeric values` part of your answer :)

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of answers already that speak in the general term of "What `if` does in programming," so let me boil your code out for you.

```
def valid_day(day):
    if day and day.isdigit():#if day
```

`if` signifies the beginning of the `if` block, and works as the other answers have pointed out. What follows is the boolean expression `day and day.isdigit()`. `and` is a Boolean operator that requires both operands (both sides of the equation, in layman's terms) to be `True` in order to evaluate as True. In this case, both `day` and `day.isdigit()` must evaluate to `True` for the `if` block to run.

In Python, we think of things as "Truthy" and "Falsey." It's easier to define "Truthy" in terms of "Falsey," because the latter is a much shorter list:

- `None`
- 0
- False
- [] "" {} () and the like

Everything else is "Truthy." If you type `while -1: print("This loops forever")` it will, in fact, loop forever. All non-zero numbers, all non-empty containers (strings, lists, dicts, sets, tuples, etc), anything not explicitly set to `False` or `None` will evaluate to `True`. In this case, the code is checking to make sure that `day` isn't `None`, because if it is then `day.isdigit()` will throw an `AttributeError` and break the code. You can try it yourself: type `None.isdigit()` in IDLE. Note that this is likely not the most foolproof implementation, since doing `valid_day(31)` will also throw `AttributeError`. `valid_day` requires a String, even though it's checking numbers.

```
        day = int(day)
        if day > 0 and day <= 31:
            return day
```

This is actually repetitive code, since doing `int(day)` confirms `day.isdigit()`. If this is your code, perhaps consider a try: except block instead, such as:

```
def valid_day(day):
    try: int(day)
    except ValueError as e:
        return False #this means whatever you passed to it can't be converted
                     #into an integer: maybe a floating point string?
    if day in range(1,32): return True
    else: return False
```

This will let you avoid the trap of checking for everything you know might fail. Instead, check to make sure your checks will be able to run, and let your program handle whatever you pass to it. This will also allow you to design a `Day` class that contains more information than an integer but will still return its calendar day using `self.__int__(): return self.calendarday` and `valid_day(Day())` will return True. In addition, your current code returns `None` when you should be returning `False` -- as I mentioned above, `None` is Falsey, so in most cases this will work (e.g. `if not valid_day: do_something_drastic()`) but in some cases you may want to deal with a boolean directly.

Okay, there's a mouthful of words for you.

TL;DR: `if` starts the `if` block, `day and day.isdigit()` is true only when day is a non-empty string that contains an integer, and the rest does what it says it does.

Comment: Thanks adsmith, your answer plus the other's answers and commentaries, give me a sense on what does that mean "if" applied to non-boolean (explicit) values. I've recently joined to this community and there is "a lot" of information and colaboration here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The value of the variable is converted to a boolean, i.e. [type coercion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) is performed. How this exactly happens depends on the language. In Python for example, an empty list evaluates to `false`. In most languages, `0` evaluates to `false` and any other number to `true`.

Then of course the variable might already contain a boolean value, e.g.

```
inBounds = day > 0 and day <= 31
if inBounds:
    #...
```

Comment: Nope. 0 is evaluates to `false` and any other numbers to `true` in reality.

Comment: This is an area where Python is somewhat different from other languages; in python, almost anything can be used in a boolean context like this.  "if foo:" means "if foo is not empty".

Comment: @dstromberg: That's why I said *"How this exactly happens depends on the language."*

Comment: @dstromberg `if foo:` in Python does *not* mean `if foo is not empty`. There are a number of ways that foo can be evaluated as False - see the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

`if day:` is a short way of writing `if day == True:`. When it evaluates the result of `True == day`, if day is a simple and basic object such as 
integer, then the Python interpreter will try to call the built-in value comparison. If day is a class, the interpreter will call its `__nonzero__` member function.

For example

```
class MyClass:
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyClass()
    if c:
        print "yes"
    else:
        print "No"
```

Comment: It's not the same. Suppose day='Friday'. then `if day` will test as true, and `if day == True` will test as False; a non-empty string has a 'true' truth value, but *all* comparisions using == between a string and a boolen value will yield False; no string is equal to a boolean value.

Comment: `if day:` is a short way of writing `if bool(day):`  or, if you prefer (and I very much don't) `if bool(day)==True:`

Answer (score 0):

As others have already provided explanations, I am just going to give some examples to make it clear.

```
# bool('') is False
if not '':
  print('Empty String')

# bool([]) is False
if not []:
  print('Empty list')

# bool(None) is False
if not None:
  print('None type')

# bool(0) is False
if not 0:
  print('Zero Value')
```

Answer (score -2):

I think in python the if condition has two different checks.

1. for regular boolean values out of an expression.
2. If some thing is 'None'.

Now the current scenario is second style too.
It is checking if `day` is `None` (to mean nothing, `null`).

Your code then is equivalent to

```
def valid_day(day):
    if day is not None and day.isdigit():#if day
        day = int(day)
        if day > 0 and day <= 31:
            return day
```

This is also a mandatory check to avoid `Null access exception` because if some object is `None` by way, it will throw exception if we try to access some methods out of that in anticipation that it is not `None`.

Comment: This is not true. `if day` evaluates `day` in a boolean context -- it has nothing to do with `None`. Actually here it's checking for the empty string.

Comment: do strings contain `isdigit()` method ?

Comment: Yes. You can easily check this.

Comment: And why are you expecting only strings will be passed as arguments to `valid_day` ?

Comment: I didn't write this code. If e.g. a nonzero int is passed, an `AttributeError` will be raised. But the function is obviously expecting strings, or it wouldn't be calling `isdigit`.

Comment: Empty string is almost equivalent to `None` though not. We check like `if (param_value is None or param_value == ''):` when we code for web server app that gets request parameters. But in general this style of coding means it is checking for `None` before making calls of an `object`'s members (methods or member variables).

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, we don't need to check for the empty string in this context, as `"".isdigit()` will return `False`. It is, in fact, checking for `None` since `None.isdigit()` will throw an `AttributeError` as you correctly asserted.

Comment: I read it that the function may be passed None -- to signify a missing day --  instead of string (and should just return None); so 'if day' is needed to avoid calling None.isdigit().

Comment: Okay. My point was that if statements have nothing to do with `None` -- they just evaluate the expression in a boolean context, and `None` happens to be false in a boolean context. The answer makes it seem like `None` is treated specially.